# Computing Asymptotic Expansion of Coefficients of Implicitly Defined Power Series

Tags: combinatorics, complex-analysis, generating-functions, analytic-combinatorics

**Background**:
I've been studying the text "Analytic Combinatorics" (amazing book!) and related papers in an effort to intuit the methods therein. My tangentially related background in spectral graph theory has provided a point of entry. However, I've needed to engage in a good bit of self-Flajolet-tion to learn the complex analysis and algebra (resultants, Newton–Puiseux methods) required to understand and execute asymptotic expansions of coefficients of implicitly defined power series associated with polynomial equations.

The sticking point right now is section VI.7. Given the implicitly defined power series for $y$,
$$
\begin{align}
y&=ze^y, 
\end{align}
$$
one can solve the characteristic equation $\phi\left(\tau\right)-\tau\phi^{\prime}\left(\tau\right)=0$ to find $\rho=\frac{\tau}{\phi\left(\tau\right)}$, the singularity of $y\left(z\right)$ closest to the origin and hence the radius of convergence of its series representation in powers of $z$ at the origin. One can then develop an asymptotic expansion of the coefficients of $y\left(z\right)$ from its series representation in powers of $(1-\frac{z}{\rho})^{\frac{1}{2}}$ about $\rho$.

Setting $y=T$ to denote Cayley trees, we see that the Table VI.14 on page 406 lists a few graph generating functions built from this class, i.e.,
$$
e^{T-\frac{1}{2}T^2},\quad \log{\frac{1}{1-T}}, \quad\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-T}}, \quad\frac{1}{\left(1-T\right)^m}.
$$

These, however, do not conform to the hypothesis that $y=z\phi\left(y\right)$.

**Question**:
How does one develop a full asymptotic expansion of the coefficients of these given knowledge of $T$? Is there a unified method?

Comment: +1 for _self-Flajolet-tion_!

Comment: I think you may find your questions answered in the lecture slides from Sedgewick's online course on analytic combinatorics. In particular, see the slides from the lecture on applications of singularity analysis: https://ac.cs.princeton.edu/online/slides/AC07-SAapps.pdf , which are part of the [online course materials](https://ac.cs.princeton.edu/online/).  More generally, you might be interested in taking the online course [Analytic Combinatorics](https://www.coursera.org/learn/analytic-combinatorics) available for free on Coursera.

Comment: I just found that the entire course videos for Analytic Combinatorics are available on YouTube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qap2MyBTSZk&list=PLoWHl5YajIf49nz2sJD3ut4emb1m8Mu5r

Comment: Thanks, awkward, especially for the lecture notes. I’m familiar with the YouTube lectures, and that does directly address on of the constructions (cycles of trees), although I think I’ll need to derive a more general form to get beyond the dominant term (descending powers of N). The composition with exp(T-T^2/2) and the 1/sqrt(1-T) and sequence construction does not appear to fit the smooth implicit schema, and the schema only admit dominant asymptotics. What is really like (and have come to learn is often too much to ask of general asymptotic methods) is an approach something like… 1/2

Comment: 2/2 “singularity analysis will work in all these cases too” as it does in the algebraic equation case (by computing the formal Puiseux series for each branch around the candidate singular points, finding the branch analytic at zero, and then transferring to an asymptotic expansion of the coefficients term-wise to one’s heart’s content).

Comment: You may use $T=ze^T\implies f(T(z))=f(0)+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{z^n}{n!}\left.\frac{d^{n-1}}{dw^{n-1}}f’(w)e^{w n}\right|_0$ from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_reversion_theorem) and truncate the sum.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To start we recall the combinatorial class specification for labeled
trees

$$\def\textsc#1{\dosc#1\csod}
\def\dosc#1#2\csod{{\rm #1{\small #2}}}
\mathcal{T} = \mathcal{Z} \times \textsc{SET}(\mathcal{T)}$$

(trees are sets of trees attached to a root node) which gives the
functional equation

$$T(z) = z \exp T(z).$$

We know by Cayley's theorem that

$$T(z) = \sum_{n\ge 1} n^{n-1} \frac{z^n}{n!}.$$

We will just do the first term of the asymptotics.

#### Tree function $T(z)$

We will take as our starting point the result by Flajolet and Odlyzko on
the nature  of the singularity of the tree function at $1/e.$
Specifically they establish on page 6 proposition 1 of the landmark
paper *Random Mapping Statistics*  INRIA RR 1114 that the tree function
has Pusieux series at a square  root singularity

$$\sqrt{1-ez}.$$

We now compute the series as in the paper *A sequence of series for the
Lambert W function* by Corless, Jeffrey and Knuth. The Pusieux series
is where we put $P=\sqrt{1-ez}$ so that $z=(1-P^2)/e$ and

$$T(z) = \sum_{k\ge 0} Q_k P^k$$

With $T(1/e) = 1$ and hence $Q_0 = 1$ we re-write the functional equation
as

$$T(z) \exp (-T(z)) = z$$ to get

$$(T-1) \exp (1-T) \exp(-1) + \exp (1-T) \exp(-1) =
\frac{1-P^2}{e}.$$

We are ready to  compute the expansion in $P$ which  we do by equating
the  coefficients on  the powers  of  $P$ on  the left  and the  right
side. Note that $(T-1)^k = Q_1^k P^k + \cdots$ so to compute the range
$Q_0$  to  $Q_m$  we  can  work   with  the  initial  segment  $T_m  =
\sum_{k=1}^m Q_k P^k.$ In particular  we also truncate the exponential
at $m.$  This is quick  and easy, the reader  may want to  establish a
recurrence  instead.   We obtain  two  branches,  of which  we  choose
numerically the  one that gives  the combinatorial branch of  the tree
function and get

$$T(z) = 1 -\sqrt{2} \sqrt{1-ez}
+ {\frac{2}{3}} (1-ez) 
-\frac{11 \sqrt{2}}{36} (1-ez)^{3/2}
+ {\frac{43}{135}} (1-ez)^2 
\\ -\frac{769 \sqrt{2}}{4320} (1-ez)^{5/2}
+ {\frac{1768}{8505}} (1-ez)^3 
- \frac{680863 \sqrt{2}}{5443200} (1-ez)^{7/2}
+ \cdots.$$

We  recall from  Wilf's *generatingfunctionolgy*  page 180
the well-known asymptotic

$${n-\alpha-1\choose n} \sim \frac{n^{-\alpha-1}}{\Gamma(-\alpha)}$$

This does not hold when $\alpha$ is a non-negative integer
due to the  poles of the Gamma function. It  does hold for
$\alpha$ a negative integer where we get

$$\frac{n^{(-\alpha)-1}}{((-\alpha)-1)!}$$

which matches the Gamma function.

We  should now  obtain Stirling's  formula from  the first
term. We find

$$\frac{n^{n-1}}{n!}
\sim -\sqrt{2} {1/2\choose n} (-1)^n \exp(n)
\\ = -\sqrt{2} {n-1/2-1\choose n} \exp(n) 
\sim -\sqrt{2} \frac{n^{-3/2}}{\Gamma(-1/2)} \exp(n)
= \frac{n^{-3/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp(n).$$

This yields on rearranging

$$\frac{n^n}{n!} \sim \frac{\exp(n)}{\sqrt{2\pi n}}$$

as desired.

#### Cycle of trees $\log\frac{1}{1-T(z)}$

These are the connected components of random mappings. We seek

$$n! [z^n] \log\frac{1}{1-T(z)}
= (n-1)! [z^{n-1}] \frac{T'(z)}{1-T(z)}.$$

Working with the initial segment of the Pusieux series we get

$$(n-1)! [z^{n-1}] 
\left[ \sqrt{2}\sqrt{1-ez} - \frac{2}{3}(1-ez) + \cdots
\right]^{-1} \times 
\left[ \frac{\sqrt{2}e}{2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-ez}} 
- \frac{2e}{3} 1\times (1-ez)^0
+ \frac{\sqrt{2}e11}{24} \sqrt{1-ez} + \cdots \right].$$

This becomes

$$(n-1)! [z^{n-1}] \frac{\sqrt{2}e}{2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-ez}}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1-ez}}
\left[1 - \frac{\sqrt{2}}{3}\sqrt{1-ez} + \cdots
\right]^{-1} \times 
\left[ 1
- \frac{2\sqrt{2}}{3} \sqrt{1-ez}
+ \frac{11}{12} (1-ez) + \cdots \right].$$

Now  expanding the  inverse term  into a  geometric series
gives  a   constant  one   plus  higher  order   terms  in
$\sqrt{1-ez}$           where            a           power
$(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{3}\sqrt{1-ez}  + \cdots)^k$  starts with
$\sqrt{1-ez}^k$  which means  fixed powers  of the  square
root  term are  only  contributed to  a  finite number  of
times. Extracting the asymptotic we thus have

$$(n-1)! [z^{n-1}] \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{1-ez}
= \frac{1}{2} (n-1)! \exp(n)
= \frac{\exp(n)}{2n} n!.$$

This matches the result from the Flajolet paper. For the formula in the
book we use Stirling to get

$$\frac{\exp(n)}{2n} \frac{n^n}{\exp(n)} \sqrt{2\pi n}
= \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{2\pi}  n^{n-1/2}$$

again as claimed.

#### A square root of the tree function $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-T(z)}}$

This time we seek

$$n! [z^n] \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-T(z)}}.$$

Once again we have from the intial segment

$$n! [z^n] 
\left[ \sqrt{2}\sqrt{1-ez} - \frac{2}{3}(1-ez) + \cdots
\right]^{-1/2}
\\ = n! [z^n] \frac{1}{2^{1/4} (1-ez)^{1/4}}
\left[1 - \frac{\sqrt{2}}{3}\sqrt{1-ez} + \cdots\right]^{-1/2}.$$

We are justified in applying the generalized binomial theorem to the
square root term as explained in the previous section. This means the
dominant asymptotic originates with

$$n! [z^n] \frac{1}{2^{1/4} (1-ez)^{1/4}}
= n! \frac{1}{2^{1/4}} {-1/4\choose n} (-1)^n \exp(n)
\\ = n! \frac{1}{2^{1/4}} {n+1/4-1\choose n} \exp(n)
\sim n! \frac{1}{2^{1/4}} \frac{n^{-3/4}}{\Gamma(1/4)} \exp(n)$$

Now use Stirling to get

$$\frac{n^n}{\exp(n)} \sqrt{2\pi n}
\frac{1}{2^{1/4}} \frac{n^{-3/4}}{\Gamma(1/4)} \exp(n)
= \frac{\sqrt{\pi} 2^{1/4}}{\Gamma(1/4)} n^{n-1/4}.$$

This matches the book, moreover we have computed the constant, which
was not given.

#### A sequence of $m$ maps $\frac{1}{(1-T(z))^m}$

This time we seek with $m$ a positive integer.

$$n! [z^n] \frac{1}{(1-T(z))^m}.$$

Do the  case $m$ odd  first. Once  again we have  from the
intial segment

$$n! [z^n] 
\left[ \sqrt{2}\sqrt{1-ez} - \frac{2}{3}(1-ez) + \cdots
\right]^{-m}
\\ = n! [z^n] \frac{1}{2^{m/2} (1-ez)^{m/2}}
\left[1 - \frac{\sqrt{2}}{3}\sqrt{1-ez} + \cdots\right]^{-m}.$$

Extracting the dominant asymptotic we find

$$\frac{1}{2^{m/2}} n! [z^n]  \frac{1}{(1-ez)^{m/2}}
= \frac{1}{2^{m/2}} n! {-m/2\choose n} (-1)^n \exp(n)
\\ = \frac{1}{2^{m/2}} n! {n+m/2-1\choose n} \exp(n)
\\ \sim \frac{1}{2^{m/2}} n! \frac{n^{m/2-1}}{\Gamma(m/2)} \exp(n)
\sim \frac{1}{2^{m/2}} \frac{n^n}{\exp(n)} \sqrt{2\pi n}
\frac{n^{m/2-1}}{\Gamma(m/2)} \exp(n)
\\ = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2^{(m-1)/2}\Gamma(m/2)} n^{n+(m-1)/2}.$$

This also matches the book where the constant was not given.

We have when $m$ is even the asymptotic works out the same
as remarked earlier. (Note that when  $m$ is odd we have a
branch cut from $1/(1-w)^{m/2}$ and when $m$ is even there
is no cut, only a  singularity at $w=1$. Both are analytic
when  $|w| \lt  1.$) Just  to be  sure we  can compute  an
alternate expression of the coefficient as a sum and check
that against the asymptotic. We get

$$(n-1)! [z^{n-1}] \frac{m}{(1-T(z))^{m+1}} T'(z)$$

which is

$$m (n-1)! \;\underset{z}{\mathrm{res}}\;
\frac{1}{z^n}  \frac{1}{(1-T(z))^{m+1}} T'(z)$$

With  $T(z)  = w$  we  get  from the  functional  equation
$z=w\exp(-w)$

$$m (n-1)! \;\underset{w}{\mathrm{res}}\;
\frac{\exp(nw)}{w^n}  \frac{1}{(1-w)^{m+1}}
\\ = m (n-1)! n^{n-1} \sum_{q=0}^{n-1}
\frac{n^{-q}}{(n-1-q)!} {q+m\choose q}.$$

This formula was tested against the asymptotic and numeric
equivalence was observed.

#### Comparison with Theorem 1

Referring to  page 6  of the random  mapping paper  we recall
that $\frac{1}{(1-T(z))^m}$ will produce the dominant asymptotic

$$\frac{1}{2^{m/2}} n! [z^n]  \frac{1}{(1-ez)^{m/2}}$$

so  that in  terms of  said theorem  we find  $\sigma(u) =
u^{m/2}$ so that $\alpha=m/2$, and $s=\exp(-1)$.  Applying
this to the closed form we quote

$$[z^n] f(z) \sim s^{-n} \frac{\sigma(n)}{n\Gamma(\alpha)}
= \exp(n) \frac{n^{m/2}}{n\Gamma(m/2)}.$$

On multiplication by $n!$ and  the scalar we indeed obtain
the asymptotic from the previous section. We see that once
the  Pusieux series  is established  the asymptotics  of a
variety of  tree function statistics can  be obtained from
the singularity analysis theorem  simply by substituting a
set of parameters into the proposed closed form.

#### Acyclic labeled graphs $\exp(T(z)-T(z)^2/2)$

Here we seek

$$n! [z^n] \exp(T(z)-T(z)^2/2).$$

To get the initial segment of the Pusieux series re-write this as

$$n! [z^n] \sqrt{e} \exp(-1/2 \times (T(z)-1)^2).$$

Expanding the exponential yields

$$\sqrt{e} \sum_{q\ge 0} (-1)^q \frac{1}{2^q}
\frac{1}{q!} (T(z)-1)^{2q}
\\ = \sqrt{e} \sum_{q\ge 0} (-1)^q \frac{1}{2^q}
\frac{1}{q!}
(-\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1-ez} + \frac{2}{3} (1-ez)+\cdots)^{2q}.$$

Observe   carefully   that   the   powers   $(1-ez)$   and
$(1-ez)^{3/2}$  appear only  in  the term  for $q=1$  with
higher    values   of    $q$   also    generating   higher
powers.  Therefore $0\le  q\le  1$ gives  the exact  first
three terms of the series. We get

$$\sqrt{e}
(1 - \frac{1}{2} (2(1-ez)
- \frac{4\sqrt{2}}{3} (1-ez)^{3/2} + \cdots))
\\ = \sqrt{e}
(1 - (1-ez)
+ \frac{2\sqrt{2}}{3} (1-ez)^{3/2} + \cdots).$$

The dominant asymptotic is therefore

$$n! [z^n] \sqrt{e} \frac{2\sqrt{2}}{3} (1-ez)^{3/2}.$$

We then  apply Theorem  1 with  $\sigma(u) =  u^{-3/2}$ so
that $\alpha = -3/2$ and with $s=\exp(-1)$ to obtain

$$n! \sqrt{e} \frac{2\sqrt{2}}{3} 
\exp(n) \frac{n^{-3/2}}{n\Gamma(-3/2)}.$$

With $\Gamma(-3/2) = \frac{4\sqrt{\pi}}{3}$ this becomes

$$n! \sqrt{e} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp(n) n^{-5/2}.$$

Use Stirling one last time

$$\sqrt{e} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} n^{-5/2}
n^n \sqrt{2\pi n} = \sqrt{e} \times n^{n-2}.$$

Exactly as given in the book. We conclude for the time being.

Comment: Wow! Quite a dissertation.

Comment: Thanks. I have worked with the random mapping paper on several occasions these past years and will continue to do so.

Comment: Amazing exposition -- thank you so much!

Comment: Great work! Extraordinary contribution!